# Floating Div not appearing in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

The following js code is for a floating div.  It's for something referred to as a  "floating ISI" which disappears depending on how far the user scrolls. Despite taking precautions, the code doesn't work in IE 7. Was wondering if anyone may have an idea of what may be the problem.

```
var floating_isi = {
ids: function (staticISI, floatingISI) {
    this.staticISI = document.getElementById(staticISI); ;
    this.floatingISI = document.getElementById(floatingISI);
    this._floatISI();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        floating_isi._floatISI();
    });
},
_floatISI: function () {
    var myHeight = 0; // var for height of browser window

    // window.innerWidth does not work in IE8 and below so we check if it gives us a number or not
    if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
        // it does work so we're not on IE8 or below
        myHeight = window.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
        //IE 6-8 in 'standards compliant mode'
        myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    };

    var T = 0; // T = distance between static ISI and top of browser window
    T += this.staticISI.offsetTop;

    if (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) {
        // pageYOffset = how many pixels down has been scrolled from original top of site                   
        T -= pageYOffset;
    } else {
        //IE8 and below do not have pageXOffset so we use this method
        var d = document.documentElement, b = document.body;
        T -= (d.scrollTop + b.scrollTop);
    }

    var difference = (T - myHeight); // distance between static ISI layer and height of browser window

    var floatingISIHeight = $(this.floatingISI).height() * -1;

    // uncomment for debugging, this renders on the hover ISI layer
    //console.log("T = " + T + " myHeight = " + myHeight + " difference = " + difference+" FloatingISIheight= "+floatingISIHeight);

    // if the difference between the layers is a certain value, then show/hide layers
    if ($(this.staticISI).is(':visible')) {
        if (difference <= floatingISIHeight) {
            $(this.floatingISI).hide();
        } else {
            $(this.floatingISI).show();
        }
    }
}
```

};

Comment: So `$(this.floatingISI).show();` is never firing?

Comment: IE7? It's working in Netscape 3 though...LoL

Comment: Have you debugged your code enough to know where within it things are going sour? this should have been something you did before posting here.